# Google Colab form as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to have a google colab form that can give a dictionary? For example, when the form is filled out, it results in a dictionary variable?

```
#@title Authorization Form
<key1> = "value1" #@param {type:"string"}
<key2> = "value2" #@param {type:"string"}
```

The above key and value pairs should be put into a dictionary automatically, instead of just being independent strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kind of a workaround could be to put the form inside a function and then call `locals()` to get a dictionary of the function's local variables.

```py
def form_dict():

    # @title Authorization Form
    Name = 'John Doe'    # @param {type: "string"}
    Age = 42    # @param {type: "integer"}

    return locals()


print(form_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'John Doe', 'Age': 42}
```

[Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18fBkF28ch5iHtD5U8L0mpiOxSX3kNguX?usp=sharing)